# cascading dropdown inside kendo grid not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid with a cascading drop down using an editor template. The problem here is when editing the drop down it is showing blank, but when you click on the drop down the rest of the functionality is working fine.

Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Locations)
    .Name("Grid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:400px" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-primary button" }); }).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LocationId).Width(140).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LocationName).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CountryId).EditorTemplateName("CountryNames").Title("CountryName").ClientTemplate("#:CountryName#").Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StateId).EditorTemplateName("StateNames").Title("StateName").ClientTemplate("#:StateName#").Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Width(100);
    })

    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => { events.Error("error_handler"); events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"); })
        .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.LocationId); model.Field(p => p.LocationId).Editable(false); })
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update_Location", "Administration"))
    )
)
```

Country Editor Template:

```
@using System.Collections
@model System.Int16?

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("CountryId")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataTextField("CountryName")
    .DataValueField("CountryId")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read => { read.Action("", "").Data("filterState"); }).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewData["Countries"])
)
<script>
    function filterState() {
        return {
            countryId: $("#CountryId").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

State Editor Template:

```
@model int?

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("StateId")
    .DataTextField("StateName")
    .DataValueField("StateId")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetGridStateList", "Administration").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("filterState"); }).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .Enable(false)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .CascadeFrom("CountryId")
)
<script>
    function filterState() {
        debugger;
        return {
            countryId: $("#CountryId").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Team,Can some one help me on this...

Comment: Nobody knew about this issue?